# How to make a separate copy of an object in Perl 6?

Tags: clone, deep-copy, raku, shallow-copy

I don't fully understand [the docs](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/clone), so I've tried `clone`, and it seems if there is an attribute of a mutable class, it can be changed in the new object using the old one (and that's what I don't want). How to make them (i.e. the copy and the original) fully separate?

```perl6
class A {
  has @.a;
}

my A $x = A.new;
my A $y = A.new;

$x.a = 1, 2;

$y = $x.clone;

$x.a.push(4);
say $y.a; # [1 2 4]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default `clone` inherited from `Mu` is shallow, as documented. This means that it will only copy the object itself, but not anything the object references. It is possible to override `clone` to have your preferred semantics, which is probably the best thing to do here.

One useful thing to know in doing this is that `clone` takes named parameters and uses them to assign to properties of the cloned object. This is worth knowing because:

- One should make sure to handle this when overriding `clone`, to avoid surprises to users of the overridden `clone` method who use this feature
- One can use this when overriding `clone` to succinctly opt in to cloning of a particular array or hash attribute

Thus for the case in the question, writing:

```
class A {
    has @.a;
    method clone() {
        callwith(:@!a, |%_)
    }
}
```

Will result in the output `[1 2]` as presumably desired. How does it work?

- The |%_ just passes on any tweaks the caller of this `clone` method specified
- `:@!a` is short for `a => @!a`
- `callwith` calls the inherited `clone` (from `Mu` in this case)
- Assignment, not binding, semantics are used on `@!a` in the target object (just as during object construction), resulting in a copy of the array

This shortcut works for hash attributes too. For an attribute containing another object, it'd look like `callsame(x => $!x.clone)`.

Comment: And if `class A` also `has @.b`, I should add `:@!b` as well? So, overriding `clone()` I should deal explicitly with all the mutable attributes?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Yes, that's is correct; for the array and hash ones, just list them out like `callsame(:@!a, :%!b, ..., |%_)`.